# Крашится приложение при выполнении AsyncTask

Tags: android-viewpager, android, android-asynctask

Я засунул в `AsyncTask` декодирование изображения и его отображение во `ViewPager`. Для каждой страницы `ViewPager` отображаются свои данные.

Проблема возникает, если начать быстро прокручивать страницы туда-сюда - тогда приложение крашится. Лог ошибок:

```
    12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment DummySectionFragment{40de0d28} not attached to Activity
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:555)
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at com.example.padmenu.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment$Task.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:307)
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at com.example.padmenu.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment$Task.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-19 14:57:40.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     ... 5 more
12-19 14:57:41.153: D/OpenGLRenderer(1259): Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-19 14:57:41.153: D/memalloc(1259): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x52c2d000 size:33005568 offset:30916608
12-19 14:57:41.153: D/memalloc(1259): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x54d1d000 size:7868416 offset:5779456
12-19 14:57:41.153: D/memalloc(1259): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5549e000 size:9957376 offset:7868416
12-19 14:57:41.233: D/OpenGLRenderer(1259): Flushing caches (mode 1)
12-19 14:57:41.744: W/dalvikvm(1259): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ae2228)
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259): crash in the same process: AsyncTask #5
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment DummySectionFragment{40dc7fb0} not attached to Activity
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:555)
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259):     at com.example.padmenu.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment$Task.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:307)
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259):     at com.example.padmenu.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment$Task.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-19 14:57:41.754: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(1259):     ... 5 more
```

Код `AsyncTask`:

```
class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Bitmap bm1, bm2;
    ImageView img1 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
    ImageView img2 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image2);
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {             
        bm1 = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),
            imgs[rnd.nextInt(10)], getPx(img1.getWidth()), getPx(img1.getHeight()));
        bm2 = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),
            imgs[rnd.nextInt(10)], getPx(img2.getWidth()), getPx(img2.getHeight()));

        return null;
    }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
          img1.setImageBitmap(bm1);
          img2.setImageBitmap(bm2);           
      }         
}
```

Comment: Нельзя получить `img.getHeight()` из фонового потока. Нужно либо передавать эти значения в AsyncTask, либо их получать в `onPreExecute()`.

Comment: проблема не в этом. отрисовка изображений происходит нормально, только вот при быстрой прокрутке приложение крашится

Comment: protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

Comment: @makavelka при каждом свайпе `ViewPager` происходит запуск `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Да, при свайпе создается фрагмент, на котором находятся imageview

Comment: судя по ошибке `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment DummySectionFragment{40dc7fb0} not attached to Activity` предположу, что вероятно нужно в `onPostExecute` сделать проверку на создание фрагмента `isAdded()` и если true, то отображать картинку.

Comment: и еще, не знаю с чем связано использование декодирования картинки в битмап. проще и нересурсозатратнее использовать `img.setImageResource(R.drawable.картинка)`.

Comment: Декодирование нужно для того, что используются большие картинки и без декодирования приложение выдавало OutOfMemory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По всей видимости проблема в том, что одновременно запущенных AsyncTask становится много. Вероятно, от лишних стоит избавиться.
Во первых, есть проверка состояния AsyncTask из внешнего кода:

```
        if(ImgURLTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
            Log.d("AsyncTask", "Еще не готово!");
            Toast.makeText(SurfaceViewActivity.this,
                "Загрузка еще не завершена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Соотв. по результатам проверки можно или не разрешать пользователям крутить пальцем до тех пор, пока AsyncTask не завершит свою работу, или наоборот, при активных телодвижениях не запускать лишних AsyncTask до тех пор, пока пользователь не угомонится.

А еще, например, можно завести переменную, которая при каждом свайпе толстеет ++, а при каждом завершении AsyncTask усыхает --. Соотв. ограничить ее, допустим до 3, и при превышении предела убивать самый старый, на текущий момент, AsyncTask, за ненадобностью.